# Partial order on matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, optimal-transport

In  *Barycenters in the Wasserstein space* https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00637399/document section 6.3 *The gaussian case Theorem 6.1*, the authors used the order on the matrix ring by claiming the set
$$
K_{\alpha,\beta}:=\{S:\alpha I\leq S\leq \beta I, S \,symmetric\}
$$
is convex and compact.

I wonder what is the definition of ordering used in this case? Is it by comparing the largest eigenvalues of matrices?

Comment: I'd expect it means $x\cdot Sx\le\beta x\cdot Ix=\beta\|x\|^{2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it sounds plausible to define that way.